# unity backface culling removes outside of my walls with blender object

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, collada

I am having problems with importing my .dae files into unity from blender.

At first some parts of my model weren't visible from the inside of my house due to backface culling. I have tried to flip those normals. This worked, however now the walls weren't visible from the outside of the house.

The next thing i've tried was extruding the wall and flipping just one side of the normals, though this caused the outer wall to be invisible and the inner wall to be visible in unity.

Is there any way to fix this properly or to disable backface culling in unity for certain parts of my model?

[Camera inside the house (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7JXJ.jpg)

[Link to the blender file (zip)](http://hurks.it/house.zip)

Comment: Can you post an image in Blender where the faces show their face normals?

Comment: @user1767754 I have included the blender project for this in the description, the problem is that the walls need to be visible from both sides as they have a certain thickness. If i enable backface culling in blender I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i looked at your mesh, and its not well made!, you have a lot of overlapping edges, and i cleaned it up a bit. You also had backface culling turned on. disabled it, flipped a few normals and it works.

> The next thing i've tried was extruding the wall and flipping just one side of the normals, though this caused the outer wall to be invisible and the inner wall to be visible in unity.

The normals were not flipped properly. You will need to reapply textures though. **Backface culling, when done properly at source** will not have to do it later in unity!.
You also need to learn how to properly create meshes without duplicate vertices or faces. As for `How to disable backface culling in unity`. [From this thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/280741/how-make-visible-the-back-face-of-a-mesh.html) it produces **wrong lighting** and have to replicate all the triangles with the script, so just stick to doing everything in blender it would be easier.

[image]

[Dropbox Link to the .blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/om4ra77sao1wa7w/house1.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you so much, this turned out to be the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not yet fixed, I would suggest that you add a solidify modifier to your model and set the thickness to a very low value. That way the walls would have volume and you wouldn't have to worry about the direction of the normals.

Answer (score -1):

You either need to use shader which supports double sided rendering, or you have to make all the polygons twice and flip the normals. Easiest way to do it is just to duplicate the mesh inside blender and flip all its normals.

Comment: Is it possible to disable backface culling in unity for a specific game object only? I have a trigger for when the player walks into the house, I am disabling the renderer for certain game objects in there, but i want the parts of the house with the renderer enabled to have backface culling disabled.

Comment: Make your own shader with boolean controlling the back facing, or use separate models